# Has this window sagged?

Tags: windows, window-frame

One of the window frames in our house looks to me like it has dropped slightly at one end. We phoned the firm who installed it (early 2016, for the previous owner of the house) and they came this morning and said that it hasn't, it's just the trim that needs re-fixing (and the handle replacing, which fell off in his hand!). He says it can't have dropped as it'll be packed underneath and bolted to the wall.

I'm still not convinced however - the gap at the top looks new, and the windowsill itself looks like it's been forced down slightly.

[image]
[image]
[image]

There is a definite draft from the gap on the right between the trim and the wall. The window itself opens and closes fine.

Any advice welcome!

Comment: There's evidence the whole house is moving. I doubt you can blame the glaziers for that.

Comment: @Tetsujin What suggests that? There's no signs of movement anywhere other than this side of this window.

Comment: The caulk lines haven't broken, but the sill has dropped away. The fill piece was bent to start with, but it hasn't moved. That caulk breaks away if there's movement, it doesn't stretch like silicone. The ceiling looks like it's moved relative to the pink wall & last time it was filled above the window. The glaziers wouldn't have used 'hard' filler, they use caulk & mastic. The frames will be screwed into the side walls each side, then held with mastic. The pieces you think have moved are just cosmetic fillets, they have no structural purpose at all.

Comment: @Tetsujin - A lot of people would blame the glaciers for that.

Comment: @HotLicks - they might, but that still wouldn't necessarily make it their fault. I live in an old Victorian house I *know* is moving. My glazing looks almost identical to the OP's & this is how it goes after 25 years in an unloved corner of the attic. The caulk discolours massively over that period so you can really see where it is [I've re-done most of the ones I see more frequently]

Comment: @Tetsujin note: glaziers v glaciers. Hot Licks was making a funny... ;)

Comment: The easiest way to know if the window or framing is moving is to lay a level on it. Put a level on that plastic piece at the bottom of the window (not the dry walled/textured window sill). It should be level. As should the top of the window and both sides. This is (or should have been) what your window guy did. You can also check the house framing (the parts that frame in the window itself) for level/square. However, be aware that these can often be a bit out of square when built brand new. Make note of any amount of out-of-level, then check in a year or two to see if it's further out.

Comment: @FreeMan - I was blaming 'DYAC' [Damn You Autocorrect, the original site for which seems to be gone from the interwebz] You can't check the trim for level. It was never levelled by the fitters, it was fit to form [& clearly has a curve in it] Had that bottom piece been an actual windowsill fit by them & not just fillets, then that would be a different issue.

Comment: Maybe that is a piece of trim that's inserted after installation - my new windows don' t have a piece that looks like that. Also, I can (and have) checked them for level. If the trim isn't level, checking along the edges of each sash should tell you a fair bit, too.

Comment: @FreeMan - they'd have put sill in if that big box section hadn't been there, or if specifically asked. My glazing could quite likely be the same make, everything I can see in the pictures is a perfect match. Most of mine could be fit to 'flat wall' except one over a kitchen worktop [in effect like their box section] but I insisted on sill. The sill is still straight & level after 25 years, some of the fillets have moved with the building [most not in any important way] Characteristic is the trim prefers to stick to the window rather than the wall if there's any movement.

Comment: … The trim, fillets, sill etc are PVC [glue] welded to the main window structure, beneath the caulk.